# Neo4j: Could I connect to kerberized cluster?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, cypher, cluster-computing, kerberos

I am using the following query to create nodes from hive (kerberized cluster) in neo4j:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:impala://host:21050/db_name;principal=impala/KEYTAB",
"select a.name from person a") YIELD row
WITH row as a
MERGE (b:Person{name:a.name})
RETURN *;
```

Do you Know if do that it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Hive with Kerberos is supported.

See the [Support for Hive with Kerberos Auth](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_support_for_hive_with_kerberos_auth) section of the APOC docs for the details.